# Vuejs plays sound periodically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This code plays a sound when I refresh the browser, but I expect it to play the sound every 15 seconds. How can I fix this problem?
When the sound is played every time I refresh, it means that fetching data from the database is working and it will play the updated sound correctly. However, the problem is that it should update periodically, not just when the user clicks refresh

Parent

```
<template>
  <div>
    <CommunicateVoice v-if="filenames.value && filenames.value[0]" :files="filenames.value[0]"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref, computed } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import CommunicateVoice from './CommunicateVoice.vue';

const lands = ref([]);
const filenames = ref([]);

onMounted(async () => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("https://koh-abx.com:50100/onboardlands");
    lands.value = res.data;

    filenames.value = computed(() => {
      return lands.value.map(item => {
        const digits = item.numbershow.toString().split('');
        return digits.map(digit => `https://koh-abx.com/sound/${digit}.mp3`);
      });
    });
  };

  fetchData();
  setInterval(fetchData, 15000);
});
</script>
```

Child

```
<template>
    <div>
      <audio ref="audioEl" />
    </div>
  </template>
  

      <script>
      import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
      
      export default {
        props: {
          files: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
          },
        },
        setup(props) {
          const audioEl = ref(null);
          const currentFileIndex = ref(0);
      
          onMounted(() => {
            audioEl.value = new Audio();
            audioEl.value.addEventListener("ended", playNextFile);
            document.body.appendChild(audioEl.value);
            audioEl.value.src = props.files[currentFileIndex.value];
            audioEl.value.play();
          });
      
          function playNextFile() {
            currentFileIndex.value += 1;
            if (currentFileIndex.value === props.files.length) {
              document.body.removeChild(audioEl.value);
              return;
            }
            audioEl.value.src = props.files[currentFileIndex.value];
            audioEl.value.play();
          }
      
          return {
            audioEl,
            playNextFile,
          };
        },
      };
      </script>
```

Comment: Any error messages in the developer console or the network tab?

Comment: Hi Yogi
 I see nothing in Chrom network tab but in Firefox it update files periodically but when I go to child component in browser in console tab show  audioEl.value.src = props.files[currentFileIndex.value];
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: <template>
  <div>
    <CommunicateVoice v-if="filenames.value && filenames.value[0]" :files="filenames.value[0]"/>
  </div>
</template>   this part it will pass the prob to child every 15 second or not

Answer (score 0):

Try appending something like a timestamp to your endpoint, this should avoid the cache since the URL would be unique, allowing the browser to fetch updated sounds every 15s without refreshing.

`https://koh-abx.com/sound/${digit}.mp3?t=${+new Date()}`